# Searching a DataFrame in polars

Tags: python, dataframe, python-polars

I'm trying to write a small python script which reads a `.parquet` file with the following schema:

| a | b | c | d |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | x | 2 | y |
| 2 | 1 | x | z |

The script takes the following arguments:

- one input file
- multiple columns
- multiple search strings (can be strings, numbers or regex)

It then searches the given columns for the given search-string and returns the whole line of the DataFrame which contains the given value in the given column.

My problem now is how to write the search correctly, because with the current implementation i get the following error if i try to search a column with a dtype different than utf8: `RuntimeError: Any(SchemaMisMatch("Series dtype UInt64 != utf8"))`

Programm execution looks like this: `pyton ./pqtmgr.py -f './test.parquet' -c 'a' -s '2'`

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# Imports
import polars
import argparse


### MAIN ###
# Main
def main():
    arguments = parse_arguments()

    dataframe = polars.read_parquet(arguments.files_input)

    dataframe = dataframe_search(arguments, dataframe)


### MISC ###
# Search DataFrame and return a result DataFrame
def dataframe_search(arguments, dataframe) -> polars.DataFrame:
    dataframes = []

    for column in arguments.columns:
        for search in arguments.search:
            dataframes.append(
                dataframe.filter(
                    (polars.col(column).str.contains(search))
                )
            )

    return polars.concat(dataframes, True, "diagonal")

### ARGUMENTS ###
# Parse given arguments
def parse_arguments():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        prog='pqtmgr.py'
    )

    # Add argument to take an input file
    parser.add_argument(
        '-f',
        '--file-input',
        dest='fils_input',
        help='''
        Takes one filepath as input file which will be searched
        ''',
        required=True
    )

    # Add argument to take a list of columns to search
    parser.add_argument(
        '-c',
        '--columns',
        dest='columns',
        help='''
            Accepts one or multiple columns that will be searched
        ''',
        nargs='*',
        required=True
    )

    # Add argument to search the given strings
    parser.add_argument(
        '-s',
        '--search',
        dest='search',
        help='''
            Accepts one or more strings or regular expression that are searched for in the given columns
        ''',
        nargs='*'
    )


# Execute Main
if __name__ == '__main__':
     main()
```

Comment: Well, the dtypes can be used to your advantage right? If you cannot cast your search string to a float and the column is not of dtype Utf8, you don't even have to search. Just need to write some type checking code.

Comment: I should indeed add some type checking and 'try casting' code... Will try to implement this in the future but for now jvz's answer does the trick even if some columns are searched unnessecarily -> inefficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming `search` is always a string, the easiest way would be to simply cast to `Utf8` before dropping into the `str` namespace if you want to search in all columns. A short example:

```py
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame({"a": [1, 2, 3], "b": ["hello", "world", "everyone"]})
search = "hello"

df["b"].str.contains(search)  # this works
df["a"].str.contains(search)  # this fails, as "a" is not of type Utf8
df["a"].cast(pl.Utf8).str.contains(search)  # this works
```

Comment: Now this works like a charm. Thank you very much!
Totally forgot about the possibility to cast the dtype of a column.